# elasticsearch mapping issue: failed to parse field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I have this mapping

```
PUT /mytest

{
  "mappings":{
        "properties": {
          "value": { "type": "object" }
        }
  }
}
```

When I insert this document

```
POST /mytest/_doc/4
{
  "value": { "value": "test"}
}
```

I got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse field [value.value] of type [long] in document with id '4'. Preview of field's value: 'test'"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse field [value.value] of type [long] in document with id '4'. Preview of field's value: 'test'",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "For input string: \"test\""
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I know the naming convention is bad, still, this is a valid JSON request, not sure why it doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2):

This error is telling you that you don't have a mapping for the property value within your value object property. The below example would property set the value.value property within your mytest index:

```
PUT mytest
{
   "mappings": {
      "properties": {
         "value": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
               "value": {
                  "type": "text"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However, I don't think that's what your intention was. As a best practice, try following the [Elastic Common Schema (ECS)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-field-reference.html) for naming your index properties.